# When does Rails wrap inserts with BEGIN and COMMIT?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to optimize my DB calls for a long rake task so I've been analyzing each and every query.

I noticed that Rails often wraps my inserts and updates with `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`. I'm not using `.transaction` anywhere so I'm confused why this is happening. I've disabled my `after_save` and `after_commit` logging but that doesn't seem to have an effect.

Any ideas? Amazon Web Services measures every single MySQL I/O so I want to get rid of these `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` statements.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe there's another way to optimize your rake task. Would you mind sharing some details?

Comment: Ultimately my goal is to reduce the MySQL I/O usage that AWS charges me for. So I assumed that I could shave some off by removing these BEGIN/COMMIT calls.

Comment: Why does your rake task has so many transactions?

Comment: I don't use transactions at all. But the rake task does do a lot of reading and writing.

Comment: You can wrap multiple reads and writes in a single transaction. This keeps Rails from opening a separate transaction for every single read and write.

Comment: How do I specify that?

Comment: That's too much for a comment, I've added an answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: BEGIN / COMMIT does not cause Disk IO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails encapsulates each write in a transaction. Example:

```
Foo.create
Foo.create
Foo.create
```

Log:

```
 (0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (6.9ms)  INSERT INTO `foos` VALUES ()
 (3.3ms)  COMMIT

 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (8.0ms)  INSERT INTO `foos` VALUES ()
 (0.4ms)  COMMIT

 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (7.3ms)  INSERT INTO `foos` VALUES ()
 (1.3ms)  COMMIT
```

If you wrap these calls in an [explicit transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html), Rails will use that transaction instead of creating new ones:

```
Foo.transaction do
  Foo.create
  Foo.create
  Foo.create
end
```

Log:

```
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `foos` VALUES ()
SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `foos` VALUES ()
SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `foos` VALUES ()
 (6.7ms)  COMMIT
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually want to get rid of them. Active Record does a lot of magic behind the scenes, so when it comes to saving complex models/relationships, the transaction wrapper is very useful for undoing database changes if something goes wrong.

Note, this has nothing to do with you using `.transaction`. Active Record is automatically wrapping common actions like `.save` and `.update_attribute` in a database transaction.

Answer (score 2):

BEGIN and COMMIT are not an overload but are the saviours I must say. They helps you to rollback your transactions if and when something goes wrong. Though you have not used `.transaction` they are by default implemented as the background Magic of Rails.

If you really want to save your buck on AWS service try for removing sumthing which does not hamper your application security or robustness.